# How to use sagas in a CQRS architecture using DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, nservicebus-sagas

I am designing a CQRS application using DDD, and am wondering how to implement the following scenario:

- a `Participant` aggregate can be referenced by multiple `ParticipantEntry` aggregates
- an `AddParticipantInfoCommand` is issued to the Command side, which contains all info of the `Participant` and one `ParticipantEntry` (similar to an `Order` and one `OrderLineItem`)

Where should the logic be implemented that checks whether the Participant already exists and if it doesn't exist, creates the Participant?

- Should it be done in a Saga that first checks the domain model for the existence of the `Participant`, and if it doesn't find it, issues an `AddParticipantCommand` and afterwards an `AddParticipantEntry` command containing the `Participant ID`?
- Should this be done entirely by the aggregateroots in the domain model itself?

Comment: "a Participant aggregate can be associated with multiple ParticipantEntry aggregates" - what do you mean?

Comment: How are they associated? By ID? What represent this "association"?

Comment: What happens if a duplicate participant is added for a `short` period of time? What is the impact to the business? It is acceptable that a human retries or cancels the command?

Comment: A Participant can be referenced by multiple ParticipantEntry aggregates (like an Order has multiple OrderItems). I edited the post.

Comment: Could you tell me more about the domain? `ParticipantEntry` and `Participant` do not seem to relate in terms of domain business.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't necessarily need sagas in order to deal with this situation. Take a look at my blog post on why *not* to create aggregate roots, and what to do instead:

http://udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/

Comment: So indeed, it's the domain model itself that should create the dependent entity, not the command handler (or Service Layer as you state in your blog post).  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

> Where should the logic be implemented that checks whether the Participant already exists and if it doesn't exist, creates the Participant?

In most instances, this behavior should be under the control of the Participant aggregate itself.

Processes are useful when you need to coordinate changes across multiple transaction boundaries.  Two changes to the same aggregate, however, can be managed within the same transaction.

You *can* implement this as two distinct transactions operating on the same aggregate, with coordination; but the extra complexity of a process doesn't offer any gains.  It's much simpler to send the single command to the aggregate, and allow it to decide what actions to take to maintain the correct invariant.

Sagas, in particular, are a pattern for reverting multiple transactions.  Yan Cui's [How the Saga Pattern manages failures with AWS Lambda and Step Functions](https://read.acloud.guru/how-the-saga-pattern-manages-failures-with-aws-lambda-and-step-functions-bc8f7129f900) includes a good illustration of a travel booking saga.

(Note: there is considerable confusion about the definition of "saga"; the NServiceBus community tends to understand the term a slightly different way than originally described by [Garia-Molina and Salem](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/andru/cs711/2002fa/reading/sagas.pdf).  kellabyte's [Clarifying the Saga Pattern](https://web.archive.org/web/20161205130022/http://kellabyte.com/2012/05/30/clarifying-the-saga-pattern/) surveys the confusion.)